# How to generate and upload CSV correctly to QuickBlox "Custom objects" module from Excel

Tags: quickblox

Before I tried to upload cvs made on excel to Custom Objects. I specify the correct name of the custom columns using upper and lower case exactly as I defined in QB custom objects table.

Also when I save the file, excel ask me to specify which kind of CSV format I want to use for the file with the next options:

Windows Comma Separated
MS-DOS Comma Separated

I tried in Windows 8 and in MacOSx Yosemite. My questions are:
- How I must define the columns name, exactly as I defined? all in uppercase?
- Which OS I should use to do generate the custom objects data?
- Which format I must use to generate it?
- Is there any other thing I must do to generate and upload the file?

I hope you can tell me what to do.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Please find an example of CSV file and a screenshot in the attachment.

You should choose class and import csv with fields.

Each field MUST has the same name as in admin panel.
[image: Please find an example on the screenshot on the picture]

Answer (score -1):

I can tell you putting quotes around one of the text fields helped. 
And you can't import a record if there's a match already in Quickblox - it will reject duplicates without any error message - it just won't import.